# In C#, is there a way to convert an array to a Stack<T> without looping?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have the following code which gives me a `Stack` containing the folder hierarchy of a path:

```
var path = @"C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\FileName.ext";

// String array with an element for each level
var folders = path.Split('\\');

var stack = new Stack<string>();

foreach(var folder in folders)
    stack.Push(folder);

var filename = stack.Pop(); // 'FileName.ext'
var parent = stack.Pop(); // 'Folder5'
var grandParent = stack.Pop(); // 'Folder4'
```

Just out of curiosity, is there a more elegant way to convert the `folders` array into a `Stack` without the `foreach` loop? Something like the (non-existent) following:

```
var folders = path.Split('\\').Reverse().ToStack();
```

I look forward to your suggestions!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`Stack<T>` has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76atxd68.aspx) that accepts `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: As does the non-generic version. It accepts an `ICollection`.

Comment: Great, thanks—I can't for the life of me figure out why I didn't think to look at the other overloads...

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
var stack = new Stack(folders);
```

Note that this still performs looping, it just does it for you.

Edit: Your code uses a `Stack` but your title asks about a `Stack<T>`. This is the non-generic version. Make your mind up :p

Comment: Oops sorry, I was paraphrasing my actual code and left out the type param... this is useful to know too though, so +1.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a `ToStack()` method, you could create an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static Stack<T> ToStack(this IEnumerable<T> sequence) {
        return new Stack<T>(sequence);
    }
}
```

Or, as the others noted, you could use the [constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76atxd68.aspx) for it.
It's a matter of personal preference I guess.